# Can Google Checkout/Wallet have two notification callbacks setup?

Tags: java, tomcat, google-checkout, android-pay

On my website I'm using Java Tomcat, and I have an application war containing webpages for my product and code for buying the product integrated with Google Wallet.

I have now added a new product with its associated webpages deployed in another war file. So I have one war file per product, but now when trying to add code for buying product 2 I realize that I need to setup Google notification callback to point to this war in my google preferences, but I cannot because it is already pointing to war 1.

So is there any way to setup **two** google notiifcation callbacks, or do I need to reorganize my code so that I either merge the two war files into one , or probably better create a third war containing all purchasing code used by both products.

Comment: I think the better solution is to create a third one that can centralize the notifications and trigger all needed sub-systems as necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - as you already know, callback api urls are set in your account, and you're only provided one.

Aside from (or instead of) creating yet another (aka "third"), perhaps tagging your orders by using [`merchant-private-data`](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Tag_Reference#tag_merchant-private-data) and/or [`merchant-private-item-data`](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Tag_Reference#tag_merchant-private-item-data) could be viable.

This way you can "segment" the orders (or items) appropriately when receiving `new-order-notification`.

Hth....

Comment: So I deployed a third store application which deal with purchasing for both products, no need to use private data as I can identify the orders no problem, the problem was I had to move code from app1 and app2 into app3 because app3 was the one to receive notifications. Still this model will probably be of benefit if I have additional products in the future and need a shopping cart model (currently customer only buy one intem at a time, and our unlikley to want to purchase more than one item at the same time)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a site per product?  You could also create multiple Checkout accounts, one for each product.

Comment: I could, but i think that creates more problems then it solves. For example the percebtage charge goes down if you sell more but thats harder if you have one product per account rather than two